# Passing a comparison operator as argument to a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, tail-recursion, first-class

What would be the best way to pass a comparison operator as an argument to a method in Ruby? I wanted to create a generic sorted? recognizer for arrays, and pass either '<=', or '>=' to this method.

So far I have this code:

```
class Array
  def sorted?
    return 1 if sorted_increasing?
    return -1 if sorted_decreasing?
    0
  end

  def sorted_increasing?
    return true if length < 2
    self[0] <= self[1] && self.drop(1).sorted_increasing?
  end

  def sorted_decreasing?
    return true if length < 2
    self[0] >= self[1] && self.drop(1).sorted_decreasing?
  end
end
```

– it appears that it would be better to have a sorted_generic?(comparison_operator) method instead of sorted_increasing? and sorted_decreasing?.

Upd: Thank you for your replies, my solution looks as follows:

```
class Array
  def sorted?
    return 1 if sorted_generic?(:<=)
    return -1 if sorted_generic?(:>=)
    0
  end

  def sorted_generic?(comparison)
    return true if length < 2
    self[0].send(comparison, self[1]) &&
        self.drop(1).sorted_generic?(comparison)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you pass a symbol, `:<`, then use `self[0].send(symbol, self[1])`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I believe I can always select a better answer instead, if someone posts it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you for your advice, I'll wait more in the future.

Comment: One advantage of this approach is that it "short-circuits" if an array is not sorted. That is, it terminates the calculation as soon as it has been determined that it's not sorted. By contrast, using `sort`. for example, requires the entire array to be examined, even if one can determine from the first two elements that it is not sorted. On the other hand, if the arrays are generally sorted, this approach would may probably be relatively inefficient.

Comment: A non-recursive "short-circuiting" way of implementing this would be to use the method [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), which returns an enumerator: `each_cons(2).all? { |n,m| n.public_send(op, m) }`.

Comment: In ruby it is idiomatic for methods ending in a `?`return a boolean rather than a bit like or comparable like response

Comment: @engineersmnky that’s true, but my professor wouldn’t care about such details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison operators are just methods in Ruby, so you could do:

```
1 <= 2 # is the same as
1.<=(2)
```

which means you can `public_send` them just as any other public method:

```
1.public_send(:<=, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Though not a direct response to your question, I suggest a different approach.

```
class Array
  def sorted?(direction)
    sorted = self.sort
    case direction
    when :increasing
      self == sorted ? 1 : 0
    when :decreasing 
      self == sorted.reverse ? -1 : 0
    else
      # <raise exception>
    end
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].sorted?(:increasing) #=>  1
[4,3,2,1].sorted?(:increasing) #=>  0
[1,3,2,4].sorted?(:increasing) #=>  0
[1,1,1,1].sorted?(:increasing) #=>  1
[1,2,3,4].sorted?(:decreasing) #=>  0
[4,3,2,1].sorted?(:decreasing) #=> -1
[1,3,2,4].sorted?(:decreasing) #=>  0
[1,1,1,1].sorted?(:decreasing) #=> -1
```

Another way is to use [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

```
class Array
  def sorted?(op)
    each_cons(2).all? { |e,f| e.public_send(op, f) } ? (op == :<= ? 1 : -1) : 0
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].sorted?(:<=) #=>  1
[4,3,2,1].sorted?(:<=) #=>  0
[1,3,2,4].sorted?(:<=) #=>  0
[1,1,1,1].sorted?(:<=) #=>  1
[1,2,3,4].sorted?(:>=) #=>  0
[4,3,2,1].sorted?(:>=) #=> -1
[1,3,2,4].sorted?(:>=) #=>  0
[1,1,1,1].sorted?(:>=) #=> -1
```

Comment: I had a similar solution on my homework that I submitted the last week. But after a week of contemplating, I more and more think that creating a sorted copy of an array in memory and comparing it to the original array is not computationally efficient, and most likely I would get some points subtracted from my grade because of that. Plus, my professor loves tail recursion, so that's why I used it here.

Comment: @wintermute `self.slice(..)` is creating a copy of the `Array` which actually seems even more inefficient.

Comment: @engineersmnky Good point, thank you. What about drop(1) then?

Comment: @wintermute I have added an answer as to how I would implement because `drop` will have the same result of creating a new `Array`

Answer (score 1):

As @CarySwoveland mentioned: 
You could also just use `Enumerable` methods `#each_cons` and `#all?`

However I would take this a step further to allow a default and custom `sorted?` mechanism.

```
class Array 
   def sorted?(sym=:<=,&block)
     block ||= ->(a,b){ a.public_send(sym,b) } 
     each_cons(2).all?(&block)
   end
end
```

This allows you the flexibility to call `sorted?` and use the anticipated `increasing` order,pass a symbol similar to `reduce` or `inject` for basic comparisons or pass a block to determine what sorted means to you.

This does not create any intermediary `Array`s in the process and short circuits on the first failure.

This now no longer limits you to basic operations e.g.

```
  array_of_hashes = [{n:9,a:1},{n:14,a:-3},{n:11, a:0}]
  array_of_hashes.sorted?
  #=> false
  array_of_hashes.sorted? do |a,b| 
    a.values.reduce(:+) <= b.values.reduce(:+)
  end
  #=> true
```

Additionally you could add some shortcut flavors like

```
class Array 
   def sorted_increasing? 
     sorted?(:<=)
   end 
   def sorted_decreasing? 
     sorted?(:>=)
   end
end
```

Such that

```
a = [1,2,3,4] 
a.sorted? == a.sorted_increasing?
#=> true
```